# VLS-TS traveling to France amid covid19

Tags: visas, france, covid-19, long-stay-visas

I have a French long-stay visa ("visa de long sejour-titre de sejour" or VLS-TS) that was recently issued in February. I was going to travel to France in the middle of March, but, due to covid-19, my trip was cancelled. 
I am trying to reschedule my flight and I want to make sure I will be allowed to enter France with my VLS-TS. I’ve been reading that only residents or people holding a VLS-TS will be allowed entrance, but I want to make sure. I travel with my emotional support dog and definitely don’t want to encounter any issues once there.

I do have all of the attestation printed and all of the documents I had when I applied for my visa. (i.e. *attestation d'hébergement,* copies of the French citizen who I live with). I’ve been living in France for the past two years.

Comment: Notice that to my knowledge there's no official recognition of _emotional support dog_ in France, so expect to not have any exceptions to rules concerning dogs if your dog is not a guide dog.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do have all of the attestation printed and all of the documents I had when I applied for my visa. ( ie: Attestation de hébergement, copies of the French citizen who I live with ). I’ve been living in France for the past two years.

Comment: Do you have a job in France that you need to start? This would probably qualify, even if you don't have a residence yet. As for the dog, there don't seem specific rules due to COVID; as said above it will be treated under the rules for pets (which may differ depending where you come from). Also, many European air carriers will require your dog to travel in the hold - check that first if it is an issue for you.

Comment: ^ I will second the comment about the _emotional support dog_ in France. The law does not recognize this, and thus you would have to get ready for that eventuality.

Answer (score 4):

The situation is dynamic and no one can predict the future. However, as of this writing, holders of French residence permits are allowed to enter France. It is not clear to me if the long-stay visa, which allows the holder to obtain a residence permit, is sufficient. You must fill out the form for an [*attestation de déplacement international*](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Attestation-de-deplacement-et-de-voyage) and bring it with you either printed out or as a QR code using the tool on the interior ministry's website and be prepared to comply with the [lock-down requirements](https://www.thelocal.fr/20200324/explained-these-are-frances-new-coronavirus-rules) upon arrival.

Comment: Do you (or anyone) know which documentation is required in addition the _attestation_? E.g. if I indicate that I have a residence, in which way do I have to prove that?

Comment: (+1) The French version of the *attestation* itself is clear: long-stay visas are covered. It also says “*titre de séjour*" (and not “*carte de séjour*“), which a VLS/TS explicitely is (TS = “*valant Titre de Séjour*”). But you also need to be a resident and I understand there are restrictions on moving (as opposed to going back to your residence), even inside the country.